# Testing dummy classifiers with score functions that require a probability estimate

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Say I define the following scoring function:

```
def multi_label_macro_auc(y_gt, y_pred):
    n_labels = y_pred.shape[1]
    auc_scores = [None] * n_labels

    # Convert the multi-class ground truth to a binary ground truth
    # by iterating through the labels
    for label in xrange(n_labels):
      auc_scores[label] =  roc_auc_score((y_gt == label)*1, y_pred[:,label])
    return np.mean(auc_scores)

ml_macro_auc_s   = make_scorer(multi_label_macro_auc, greater_is_better=True, 
                               needs_threshold=False, needs_proba=True)
```

And I learn a `DummyClassifier` on my data:

```
dummy_clf = DummyClassifier(strategy='stratified',random_state=0)
dummy_clf.fit(X,y)
```

If I then try to test this dummy classifier against my scoring function:

```
ml_macro_auc_s(dummy_clf, X, y)
```

scikit-learn complains with:

```
"ValueError: AUC is defined for binary classification only"
```

I tried passing a `probability=True` to `DummyClassifier`, but it does [not](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html) seem to accept that parameter:

```
dummy_clf = DummyClassifier(strategy='stratified'',random_state=0, probability=True)
```

How can I apply my own scorers that require soft outputs to a `DummyClassifier`?

### Update:

- `y` is a 1D array with values in the range `[0,1,2]`
- `X` is  a feature array with the same number of rows as y and `125` columns

Comment: What is in y? I would imagine it contains more than two kinds of labels - which is what the error message tells you.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasMueller. I have updated the post. Just wanted to note that the scorer I defined above works well with regular classifiers in multi-class problems (e.g. when using `SVC` OVA). The scorer iterates through the labels and computes the average of the `roc_auc_scores` (see the comments in the function definition)

Comment: The strategy should go to the definition of the scorer, not the classifier, right?